# Why doesn't `iftop -s` generate output on the fly?

Tags: iftop

I tried to make `iftop` execute for 80000 seconds and output to a file:

```
sudo iftop -i wlan0 -s 80000 -t > "$file"
```

However all I can find in the file is

```
Listening on wlan0
```

without the actual output. When I remove the `-s 80000`, then it works fine.

Why is there no actual output in the file?

Answer (score 0):

`iftop -h` says `-s num` prints one *single* text output *after* `num` seconds, then quits.

If you check the file when `iftop` is still collecting data, the result will not yet be there. With `-s 80000` the tool should exit after 22+ hours. Read the file *then*.

---

To capture more than one chunk of output:

- Run `iftop -t -s …` several times in a loop. Note there's overhead: `-s 1` can take 2 seconds or so; therefore the number of loops does not simply translate to total time in this case. And total statistics ("cumulative" etc.) will be independent in each loop, so this is not the best approach. You would want to append (`>>`) each time or redirect the output from the entire loop.
- Use `timeout`. Example:

  ```
   sudo timeout -s INT --foreground 20 iftop -i wlan0 -t
  ```

  `timeout --foreground … sudo …` seems safer but it will most likely not work because children of `sudo` will not be timed out.
- <strike>Run `iftop -t … > …` in the background, `sleep` as long as you wish and finally kill `iftop`.</strike>

  Not working because `iftop` wants to use the terminal anyway. A cumbersome workaround is to run `iftop` in the foreground, then `sleep` and `kill` in another terminal.

Comment: ah ok, how can I make it display everything and not a single  test output?